# Shorten jQuery multiple children selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, children

I feel like this is not right way of selecting data:

```
$(document).on('blur', 'td', function(){   
cID = $(this).children('div.cColor')
                 .children('select.dropdown.cColor_dropdown')
                 .children("option")
                 .filter(":selected")
                 .data("cid");
}
```

Is there any possible way of shortening this tedious selector? 
edit: html

```
 <tr>   
        <td class="cID">
            <div class="cColor">
                <select class="dropdown cColor_dropdown" >
                <option data-cID="21" value="client_name">client_name</option>
                <option data-cID="22" value="2_client_name">2client_name</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>   
    <td class="cID">
                <div class="cColor">
                    <select class="dropdown cColor_dropdown" >
                    <option data-cID="21" value="client_name">client_name</option>
                    <option data-cID="22" value="2_client_name">2client_name</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more helpful if you provide markup (HTML).
There are many options:

```
cID = $(this).find('div.cColor>select.dropdown.cColor_dropdown>option:selected').data("cid");
cID = $(this).find('option:selected').data("cid"); // if there is only one select
cID = $(this).find('select#select-id>option:selected').data("cid"); // select with id
cID = $(this).find('select#select-id option:selected').data("cid"); // if select specified, no need for >
```

Comment: first suggestion works and as there is more then one select without id